# ColdFusion PDF file search using cfsearch and SOLR extremely slow

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, solr, indexing, cfsearch

I have a functional working Adobe ColdFusion application that is indexing roughly 2k PDF files with via Solr search and providing expected results - however each search query to the collection takes generally 25-30 seconds.

This is how I indexed the 2k PDF files to Solr:

```
<!--- query database files --->
<cfset getfiles = application.file.getfiles()>

<!--- create solr query set --->
<cfset filesQuery = QueryNew("
    fileUID
    , filepath
    , title
    , description
    , fileext
    , added
")>

<!--- create new file query with key path and download url --->
<cfoutput query="getfiles">
<cfset ext = trim(getfiles.fileext)>
<cfset path = expandpath('/docs/#fileUID#.#ext#')>

<cfscript>
    newRow = QueryAddRow(filesQuery);
    QuerySetCell(filesQuery, "fileUID","#fileUID#" );
    QuerySetCell(filesQuery, "filepath","#path#" );
    QuerySetCell(filesQuery, "title","#filename#" );
    QuerySetCell(filesQuery, "description","#description#" );
    QuerySetCell(filesQuery, "added","#added#" );
</cfscript>

</cfoutput>

<!--- index the bunch --->
<cfindex  
    query = "filesQuery" 
    collection = "resumes" 
    action = "update" 
    type = "file" 
    key = "filepath"     
    title = "title" 
    body = "title, description"
    custom1 = "fileext"
    custom2 = "added"
    category= "file"
    status = "filestatus">
```

This is how the files are being searched and where the (25-30 second) Solr search happens:

```
<!--- imagine form with (form.search) for terms --->

<cfsearch name = "results" 
    collection = "resumes" 
    criteria = "#form.search#
    contextPassages = "1"
    contextBytes = "300"
    maxrows = "100"
    contextHighlightBegin = "<strong>"
    contextHighlightEnd = " </strong>">

<!--- show (results) query --->
```

Some additional info on the project: all of the files are less than 1 page in length, so there was no character cutoff in creating the index results to Solr.  I have played with the Solr buffer limit within the ColdFusion Administrator with no major discernable change in time (currently at 40).  I am on a development VM with MS Server 2003, 1.86 Xeon - Adobe ColdFusion 9.0.1 and 1GB RAM.  JVM is Sun Microsytems (14.3-b01). Almost nothing else is running server-side, so performance should be unaffected by external factors.

It is providing expected and perfect results, just not in a timely fashion.

Comment: UPDATE!!!  The issue ended up being the combination of a cfsearch and cfdump bottleneck, causing searches to take around 30 seconds per search.  I was using that combination of tags to ensure that the expected results were appearing.

As soon as the collection was queried via cfsearch and results returned via cfloop query - all performance issues were fixed.  The collection now processes what is now almost 3k records in about 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [CFSolrLib](http://cfsolrlib.riaforge.org/). It uses the Solr API. Its possible you may get a performance boost by bypassing `<cfsearch>`